# Xamarin JAR binding not creating a binding for derived class from android.app.IntentService

Tags: java, android, binding, jar, xamarin

I am trying to create an Android Java binding library.
I have a class that that extends IntentService and I need it to be exposed in C#. When I build the project I got the following warning:

> Warning BG8102: Class eu.mypackage.UI.MyIntentService has unknown base type android.app.IntentService (BG8102)

Is there a way to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end I found temporary solution. I have added IntentService class to my jar and make my extended IntentService extends IntentService from the package. It works.