# Warning BG8102: has unknown base type android.app.IntentService. (BG8102). When Binding a Java android Library to Xamarin

Tags: java, c#, xamarin, java-binding

I am Working on BLE project on Xamarin. Currently I am working on the Over-The-Air Device Firmware Upgrade (OTA-DFU) part. I am planing to use the [native java Android DFU Library](https://github.com/NordicSemiconductor/Android-DFU-Library) on Xamarin.

I am following the [documentation on binding Java library to Xamarin](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/java_integration_overview/binding_a_java_library_(.jar)/).

In the end the compiler displays `Warning BG8102: Class NO.Nordicsemi.Android.Dfu.DfuBaseService has unknown base type android.app.IntentService. (BG8102) (AndroidDUFLibrary)`. I was enable to reference the converted java library in Xamarin. But some class are missing and I cannot reference it.

Could you please let me know how can I fix the missing class issues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27902506/xamarin-jar-binding-not-creating-a-binding-for-derived-class-from-android-app-in). The missing class issue was fixed when I manually add the `IntentService` source code to my project (create new `IntentService` file and paste the `IntentService` source code) and made custom package name inside the `IntentService` source code (e.g. com.mynewpackage). Then I replace the `IntentService` as `com.mynewpackage.IntentService` everywhere in my project.

It's kind of ugly solution. We have to manually add source code files for the missing classes one by one in the project. It would be better to change some configuration in the compiler to automatically fix the missing class issue.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a bit old, but in case someone else is searching for this, another solution I found is to simply reference the Xamarin component of the IntentService by modifying the Metadata.xml file.

```
<attr path="api/package[@name='The.Package.Here']/class[@name='TheClassHere']" name="extends">mono.android.app.Intentservice</attr>
```

That way there is no need to manually add the source code like the solution posted before.

Comment: <attr path="api/package[@name='no.nordicsemi.android.dfu']/class[@name='DfuBaseService']" name="extends">android.app.Intentservice</attr>
Did this. didn't help - still the same error